# React-Redux Chrome Extension getting error that action type is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

We've build our chrome extension on react-redux using the react-chrome-redux see: https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux

I am trying to send an action and make a http call. We're using axios. We are getting an error: `Actions may not have an undefined "type" property`

With the react-chrome-redux library package there is a call that is supposed to simulate thunk functionality, `dispatchResponder`, but I'm not understanding it. I send my action, but continuously get a action type is undefined error see: https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux/wiki/Advanced-Usage#action-responses

Here is the dispatch in the component. There is a handleChange function that updates the state with the user's input values (email, password) with some validation

```
handleLogin = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { email, password } = this.state;

  if (email && password) {
    this.props.login(email, password);
  }
}

....

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        login: function (email, password) {
            dispatch(login(email, password))
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @property {object} classes
 * @property {object} theme
 * @property {object} user - User logging in
 * @property {object} login - authentication attempt
 */
Login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Login));
```

This is the action that gets triggered with `login`

```
export function login(email, password) {

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request(email));
    const data = { "email": email, "password": password };

    const login = axios({
      // make post request to auth service
    });

    login.then(
      response => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        dispatch(success(response.data));
      },
      error => {
        dispatch(failure(error));
        dispatch(alertActions.error(error.message));
      }
    );
  };

  function request(email) { return { type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST, email } }
  function success(user) { return { type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
  function failure(error) { return { type: types.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

And my reducer. The reducer is imported correctly into the reducer/index.js file

```
import * as types from "../constants/constants";
import * as actions from "../actions/authActions";

let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const initialState = user ? { loggedIn, user, loading } : {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case types.LOGIN_REQUEST:

      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: What's in `../constants/constants` - is `types.LOGIN_REQUEST` defined? And are you importing it correctly in the file that contains the login function?

Comment: `../constants/constants` are my action types. So I import constants as `types` and call them `types.LOGIN_REQUEST`. LOGIN_REQUEST is defined there `export const LOGIN_REQUEST = "LOGIN_REQUEST";`

Comment: This particular organization of code, ie, using constants as my action types, was taken from a boilerplate I had been looking at

Comment: If in the action creator I return something like `return { type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST, email }` There is no error. I think there is something happening with my `dispatch =>` in the action creator

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in Chrome with breakpoints to see what the contents of the action is?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse I'm not sure what you mean. I know the action's contents because I created it. The issue, I think, is something with the thunk middleware